# PayPal Subscription Button for Recurring Payments

Tags: php, html, css, paypal

**Paypal did not get Response**

HI ,

I m using https://www.formget.com/paypal-subscription/ tutorial. followed above website(tutorials) code. but there is no use of this code. because of i did not get any response to success.php page.i get errors only. please check the image. i tried so many times. i m using two or more paypal address. but i did not get any response to sandboxpaypal.

i did not get sandbox paypal response. if i get response what i will do for sandbox paypal.

paypal did not get response:

[image: Screenshot of 'payment failed' message along with PHP warnings]

help to me

Comment: It seems from that error page you did get something sent to success.php. There's an error on that page. Look at $product_transaction in success.php. What is is set to?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer,

Go to the sandbox PayPal profile/account page.

[image: PayPal profile/account page screenshot]

Change data transfer Option

[image: Change data transfer option screenshot]

Now I get the data correctly.

Thanks